# Why can't I max out Shedinja's affection in Pokémon Amie?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a Shedinja in Pokemon Y, and I'm trying to max out its affection. I got it up to the 4th heart on the affection meter and leveled it up twice like other posts said to do.

I went back to Poke-Amie (after leveling my Shedinja) and I kept petting it and playing games with it yet nothing happened... I tried again, another 2 levels, more petting and playing... nothing happened again. I tried a third time all over again and STILL nothing happened.

I've maxed out other Pokemon's affection and it worked just fine on them but for some reason not on my Shedinja. I was wondering if its impossible to max out a Shedinja's affection on Poke-Amie? Or is there some other factor im missing?

Comment: "leveled it up twice" - do you mean actual fight-enemies-and-level-up levels, or do you mean petting and playing with it until you get the super-heart-release thing twice? Actual levels have nothing to do with Pokemon-Amie. You just need a crapton of hearts.

Comment: Actually fighting and gaining exp

Comment: oh really? I got the ton-of-hearts thing once on my shedinja, how can I get it again? just petting and playing? because I cant feed it so im guessing that's the only possible way.

Comment: Yup. Keep doing that.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on what user2357112 mentions, your Pokémon raises its Affection by 'collecting' hearts. Each time you reach a certain threshold of hearts, your Pokémon will do a little animation (usually a dance or spin, but it varies from Pokémon to Pokémon), and a lot of hearts will come out from your Pokémon.

The number of hearts you need to collect for each level of affection are:

- Level 1 = 1 heart (Start)
- Level 2 = 50 hearts
- Level 3 = 100 hearts
- Level 4 = 150 hearts
- Level 5 = 250 hearts (Full Affection)

You gain hearts by petting & feeding your Pokémon. You can only pet and feed them so much in one turn however - once they stop giving hearts (and refuse food) you need to do something else.

The easiest method I've found is to alternate petting/feeding and playing the minigames.  The steps are:

- Pet them until they don't give off hearts anymore
- Feed them until they eat slowly (they will refuse the next one)
- Play one minigame
- Repeat

Check out the [Pokémon Amie](http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemonamie.shtml) page on Serebii for more info.

Side note: Affection is not the same thing as Happiness. Happiness is affected by walking, leveling up, fainting etc, It affects the power of the moves Return and Frustration, and is the method to which a lot of Pokemon evolve. Affection will make Eevee evolve into Sylveon, Happiness will make it evolve into Espeon (day) or Umbreon (night)

Comment: It should probably be noted that Shedinja does not eat ;)

Answer (score 2):

Experience levels don't affect Pokemon-Amie. Affection is based on the hearts your Pokemon releases after you feed or pet it. Your Pokemon will unleash a particularly dramatic burst of hearts each time it gains a level of affection up to level 4; the final level of affection takes two such bursts. Just keep playing with your Shedinja and petting it, and its affection will eventually max out.